# Jquery: Closest() row remove not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint-online

I have a script that adds a set of rows to allow you to capture information for an additional visitor in a SharePoint List Form. I have two anchor tags, one for add and the other for remove. When I add a new visitor it works, and also when I remove the visitor it still works but If I try to add again it brings back the previously removed rows plus the newly added row. Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

The script and source I have written:

```
function addVisitor(sender) {
    var newVisitor = "<tr class='newVisitor'><td nowrap='true' valign='top' width='113px' class='ms-formlabel'><span class='ms-h3 ms-standardheader' ><nobr>Visitor name</nobr></span></td><td valign='top' width='350px' class='ms-formbody'><span dir='none'><input type='text'  maxlength='255'  title='Visitor name' class='ms-long ms-spellcheck-true'><br></span></td></tr><tr><td nowrap='true' valign='top' width='113px' class='ms-formlabel'><span class='ms-h3 ms-standardheader' ><nobr>Visitor surname</nobr></span></td><td valign='top' width='350px' class='ms-formbody'><span dir='none'><input type='text'  maxlength='255'  title='Visitor surname' class='ms-long ms-spellcheck-true'><br></span></td></tr><tr><td nowrap='true' valign='top' width='113px' class='ms-formlabel'><span class='ms-h3 ms-standardheader' id='Visitor_x0020_email'><nobr>Visitor email*</nobr></span></td><td valign='top' width='350px' class='ms-formbody'><span dir='none'><input type='text' value='' maxlength='255'  title='Visitor email Required Field' style='ime-mode : ' class='ms-long ms-spellcheck-true'><br></span></td></tr><tr style='display:none;' class='vReg'><td nowrap='true' valign='top' width='113px' class='ms-formlabel'><span class='ms-h3 ms-standardheader' id='Vehicle_x0020_registration'><nobr>Vehicle registration</nobr></span></td><td valign='top' width='350px' class='ms-formbody'><span dir='none'><input type='text' value='' maxlength='255' title='Vehicle registration' style='ime-mode : ' class='ms-long ms-spellcheck-true'><br></span></td>" + addBtn + "</tr>";

    $(newVisitor).insertAfter(sender);
if (hideReg)
    $('.vReg').hide();
else
    $('.vReg').show();

$('.add').on('click', function () {
    var sender = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
    $(this).hide();
    addVisitor(sender);
    $('.add').hide();
    $('.add:last').show();

});

$('.remove').on('click', function () {
    var sender = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
    $(this).hide();
    $('.add').hide();
    removeVisitor(sender);
    $('.add:last').show();
});

}

function removeVisitor(sender) {
    var rowPos = $(sender).index();
    $(sender).remove(); // remove current
   // $('.ms-formtable tr').eq(rowPos - 1);
    for (var i = 1; i<=4; i++) {
        $($('.ms-formtable tr')[rowPos - i]).remove();
    }      

}
```

Comment: Create working fiddle with test data and share the URL. Then we can check.

Comment: I think "$(this).closest('tr')[0]" here no need indexing when jQuery selector just try with "$(this).closest('tr')"

Comment: I suggest you provide the full code(HTML+JavaScript) for further research.

Comment: @LZ_MSFT I updated the code on my question.

Comment: @Hanif I removed that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the event attachments out of the `addVisitor` method.

```
$('.remove').on('click', function () { ... }
```

And

```
$('.add').on('click', function () { ... }
```

If not, the app will have a buggy behavior because every time the code calls the method `addVisitor` it will add a new handler to the event, resulting in more than one call to the callback function when the user clicks on elements with the class `.add` or `.remove`.

So the resulting code would be:

```
function addVisitor(sender) {
    var newVisitor = "<tr class='newVisitor'><td nowrap='true' valign='top' width='113px' class='ms-formlabel'><span class='ms-h3 ms-standardheader' ><nobr>Visitor name</nobr></span></td><td valign='top' width='350px' class='ms-formbody'><span dir='none'><input type='text'  maxlength='255'  title='Visitor name' class='ms-long ms-spellcheck-true'><br></span></td></tr><tr><td nowrap='true' valign='top' width='113px' class='ms-formlabel'><span class='ms-h3 ms-standardheader' ><nobr>Visitor surname</nobr></span></td><td valign='top' width='350px' class='ms-formbody'><span dir='none'><input type='text'  maxlength='255'  title='Visitor surname' class='ms-long ms-spellcheck-true'><br></span></td></tr><tr><td nowrap='true' valign='top' width='113px' class='ms-formlabel'><span class='ms-h3 ms-standardheader' id='Visitor_x0020_email'><nobr>Visitor email*</nobr></span></td><td valign='top' width='350px' class='ms-formbody'><span dir='none'><input type='text' value='' maxlength='255'  title='Visitor email Required Field' style='ime-mode : ' class='ms-long ms-spellcheck-true'><br></span></td></tr><tr style='display:none;' class='vReg'><td nowrap='true' valign='top' width='113px' class='ms-formlabel'><span class='ms-h3 ms-standardheader' id='Vehicle_x0020_registration'><nobr>Vehicle registration</nobr></span></td><td valign='top' width='350px' class='ms-formbody'><span dir='none'><input type='text' value='' maxlength='255' title='Vehicle registration' style='ime-mode : ' class='ms-long ms-spellcheck-true'><br></span></td>" + addBtn + "</tr>";

    $(newVisitor).insertAfter(sender);
    if (hideReg)
        $('.vReg').hide();
    else
        $('.vReg').show();       
}

function removeVisitor(sender) {
    var rowPos = $(sender).index();
    $(sender).remove(); // remove current
   // $('.ms-formtable tr').eq(rowPos - 1);
    for (var i = 1; i<=4; i++) {
        $($('.ms-formtable tr')[rowPos - i]).remove();
    }            
}


$('.add').on('click', function () {
    var sender = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
    $(this).hide();
    addVisitor(sender);
    $('.add').hide();
    $('.add:last').show();

});

$('.remove').on('click', function () {
    var sender = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
    $(this).hide();
    $('.add').hide();
    removeVisitor(sender);
    $('.add:last').show();
});
```